# Can't resolve @reach/dialog

Tags: typescript, webpack, node-modules

I'm developing a React app with typescript. I try to import `@reach/dialog`, but it fails with the `Module not found` error`on its dependencies (`react-focus-lock`,`react-remove-scroll`and`prop-types`).

My own script compiles. And some other libraries compiles as well, e.g. `react-simple-tree-menu`. But when I try to import `@reach/dialog`, it breaks with the following errors:

```sh
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-focus-lock/dist/es2015/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './MoveFocusInside' in '/Users/huang.ming.chang/Documents/feedback-widget/node_modules/react-focus-lock/dist/es2015'
 @ ./node_modules/react-focus-lock/dist/es2015/index.js 3:0-48 6:0-75
 @ ./node_modules/@reach/dialog/es/index.js
 @ ./src/components/Modal.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-remove-scroll/dist/es2015/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component' in '/Users/huang.ming.chang/Documents/feedback-widget/node_modules/react-remove-scroll/dist/es2015'
 @ ./node_modules/react-remove-scroll/dist/es2015/index.js 1:0-43 2:0-25
 @ ./node_modules/@reach/dialog/es/index.js
 @ ./src/components/Modal.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/prop-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './factoryWithTypeCheckers' in '/Users/huang.ming.chang/Documents/feedback-widget/node_modules/prop-types'
 @ ./node_modules/prop-types/index.js 14:19-55
 @ ./node_modules/@reach/dialog/es/index.js
 @ ./src/components/Modal.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
```

I also tried to modify my webpack to only import `main` instead of `module` (by changing `mainFields to ['main']), so that it only imports es5 format. However, it still failed to resolve.

I tried to use `create-react-app` to create a blank app and import `@reach/dialog` and it builds correctly. So, apparently my webpack config is outdated.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this

```
module.exports = {
    mode: isDev ? MODES.DEV : MODES.PROD,
    target: "web",
    devtool: isDev ? "eval-source-map" : false,
    entry: './index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: './dist'
        filename: `main.js`,
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            config: {
                                path: paths.confDir
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: `[name].[ext]`,
                            outputPath: `${widgetUIDir}/images`
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["js", "jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        modules: ["node_modules"]
    },
    externals: ["react", "react-dom"],
    plugins: [...some plugins]
};
```

My `ts.config.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Please help point out where I did wrong. This config works with some old packages, but for some new packages it always encounters this issue.

How to configure webpack so that it can transpile es6 code from `node_modules`?

And why my webpack is unable to resolve es5 code in `@reach/dialog`?

Thanks!